# HTTP2 support in MAMP Pro

Tags: apache, nginx, mamp, http2, mamp-pro

Is there any way to enable HTTP2 support in MAMP Pro? I want to test and improve some of my local development websites with HTTP2 support.

I've been searching for a while now, but haven't found a single solution.

Comment: I would recommend a docker setup instead of MAMP. With docker you will be much more flexible.

Comment: Did you solve it? Would like to know too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I configured HTTP2 for NodeJS APP on MAMP Pro with NGINX. I wrote short article about it https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nodejs-http2-server-mamp-pro-nginx-sergei-iastrebov/ I think it'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

As Tarun has stated the versions of Apache and Nginx included in MAMP pro do not support HTTP/2. Additionally HTTP/2 requires a modern version of OpenSSL (1.0.2) to support HTTP/2 on most browsers.

Your best options are therefore to change Apache and/or Nginx to support this. You can then copy the appropriate config to connect up to the rest of the MAMP stack (e.g. MySQL, PHP..etc.).

If you are on Windows then [ApacheHaus](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx) and [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) offer up to date Apache versions with HTTP/2 support. Or if you prefer Nginx then can [download these directly from Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html).

If you are on MacOS then [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) allows you to install up to date versions of Apache and Nginx.

Alternatively you can use a Docker image if set up for that, or can compile from source (relatively simple for MacOS as very similar as for linux, but a good bit more complicated for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nginx you can just add following code into your server block or http block (for global) to the nginx.conf

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
```

Otherwise, if Apache you can do above, then open Nginx setting and enable "Use Nginx as a Reverse Proxy of Apache"

Answer (score 0):

For MAMP Pro `v4.0.0`

```
C:\>F:\MAMP\bin\nginx\nginx.exe -V
nginx version: nginx/1.13.1
built by cl 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --sbin-path=nginx.exe
--http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs/lib/pcre --with-zl
ib=objs/lib/zlib --with-openssl=objs/lib/openssl --with-select_module --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/Nebojsa/subsmodule/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Nginx is not built with `HTTP2` support

```
C:\>F:\MAMP\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.31 (Win32)
Server built:   May  6 2016 10:19:53
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:40
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-Util 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-Util 1.5.4
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     WinNT
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     no
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/winnt"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/apache"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error.log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

If you look at Apache HTTP2 module

> **Apache Module mod_http2**
>
> Available Languages:  en
>
> Description:  Support for the HTTP/2 transport layer
>
> Status:   Extension
>
> Module Identifier:    http2_module
>
> Source File:  mod_http2.c
>
> Compatibility:    Available in version 2.4.17 and later

The minimum version of Apache is not met with MAMP Pro 4 using Apache `2.2.31`.

So you can't use the HTTP2 module. It is better off to use other newer version apache through docker or directly to work with HTTP2